# Bulk Insert from csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv

I am trying to do a bulk insert from a .csv file. I found that some of the data in certain columns has some special characters like / . This blocks the import from happening. How can I get pass that issue without editing the csv manually? Here is the code I am using:

```
    BULK INSERT dbo.MYDATABASE
    FROM 'D:\Import.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        TABLOCK
    )
GO
```

Comment: `/` isn't a special character. Special characters are `,` or newlines inside fields. What does the CSV look like?

Comment: noted but the / is blocking the import from happening.

Comment: It doesn't. There's something else in there that's causing problems. Post an example of the CSV and mention which SQL Server version you target. Full CSV support (indluding row separators in fields) was added in 2017

Comment: Post the *actual, full* error message too, if you get one. If not, explain how you realized the import failed - did you get less rows than expected? Truncated rows? Perhaps one last huge field?

Comment: If `/` caused issues people would be unable to import fiels that contained eg xml snippets.

Comment: I deleted each column up to the point where it started to actually import the data. I went to the column that caused the issue and replaced the / with a - when I ran the script again everything imported. There is no error it just says 0 rows affected

Comment: Post your data. People can't *guess* what your file contains. What you claim is so big it would be noticed by *someone* in the last 20 years.

Comment: I will find a work around thanks

Comment: Workaround for **what**??? You haven't described any problem yet. Trying to fix what isn't broken is how big bugs get embedded in applications so deep that it's impossible to fix them afterwards - too many things end up depending or reversing the "fix", making it impossible to actually fix whatever the problem was

Comment: I cannot load my full data file. The problem I found is the exact problem i described. The file does not want to import it gives me a message that 0 rows affected. I deleted all data in columns B - G and import worked.  I then added the data back in B and so on till the data didn't import anymore. I then knew that the problem must be in column G in the csv. I started by just replacing the / with a - and the import worked. So by ways of elimination i determined that the must be the problem.

Comment: You can load the first couple of lines. You can load the line that contains the problem. Right now you haven't described anything nor proved any problem. I can easily load a file with slashes, and so can thousands of other developers

Comment: I suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Anyway, no repro. I can insert values like `c:/path1/file1.txt` *and* `c:/path1/file1.txt` just fine

Comment: I understand what you are saying and that is why i was confused aswell. I am working through the data again. Give me a second to just see if I can find something else. I added a line to the top where / was in the last column and import was fine. There must be some other issue somewhere. The frustration is that sql isn't giving me an error.

Comment: Ok so the strangest thing is happening here. This is a file I receive from the client. I couldn't find any errors in the data but still no import....but...when i open the csv file and re save as the same .csv it it actually works and data imports.